# Functionnals tests with Symfony4 on Forms (EntityType input) didn't work

Tags: forms, phpunit, entity, symfony4, functional-testing

I have a form for Product Entity

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if ($options['edit'] === false) {
        $builder
            ->add('code', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Code',
        ])
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Nom',
        ]);
    }

    $builder
        ->add('competence', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'Compétence',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'class' => Competence::class,
            'required' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

It's works but when I want to write functionnal test it didn't work. While my unit tests are working.
For testing, i've a database AND database_test. For this I use the .env.local and .env.test.local with the right DATABASE_URL (main and test).

```
public function testAdd()
{
    // Instance du client HTTP
    $client = static::createHttpBrowserClient();

    // Construction de la requête GET sur la page product
    $crawler = $client->request(
        'GET',
            getenv('APP_TEST_URL') . '/product/new'
        );
        
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Ajouter')->form([
            'product[name]' => 'Product Test',
            'product[code]' => 'ABC_DEF',
            'product[competence]' => $this->entityManager->getRepository(\App\Entity\Competence::class)->findOneBy(['name' => 'BVB'])->getId(),

        ]);

        $client->submit($form);

        $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

        $this->assertSame(1, $crawler->filter('div.alert.alert-success')->count());
    }
```

How I setup this :

```
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        $client = static::createHttpBrowserClient();
        $client->restart();
    }
```

My problem is about the EntityType Competence. I've to put the Id that I want but for the same Competence in Database and Database_URL, ids are not the same.

So I get this error :

1. App\Tests\E2e\Controller\ProductControllerTest::testAdd
   InvalidArgumentException: Input "product[competence]" cannot take "3" as a value (possible values: "", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279").

Even if I enter "258", for example, I've this error :
"LogicException: The request was not redirected." on the followRedirect().

I don't know if I'm on the right way, but I'm lost right now. I tried a lot of things with doctrine.yaml and .env.*

Comment: In the test-system, does the non-test database exists and is accessible? Can you drop (or misconfigure) it and run without it?

Comment: I don't know if the problem is from database :/
I tried to change values in my form : from ids to name. Now i've the same in database and database_test. But I still have the same error on followRedirect... 

1) App\Tests\E2e\Controller\ProductControllerTest::testAdd
LogicException: The request was not redirected.

Comment: Don't the high-numbered ids suggest that the wrong database is in use?